# How to get LNC as a theorem using Frege's Prop Calculus?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, philosophy

So Im using axioms from,[Frege propositional calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege%27s_propositional_calculus#:%7E:text=It%20makes%20use%20of%20just,one%20inference%20rule%3A%20modus%20ponens.&text=Frege%27s%20propositional%20calculus%20is%20equivalent,standard%20PC%22%20with%2011%20axioms.) and is there any way to derive Law of non contradiction as theorem from them.

The axioms

1. A → (B → A) | THEN-1
2. (A → (B → C)) → ((A → B) → (A → C)) | THEN-2
3. (A → (B → C)) → (B → (A → C)) | THEN-3
4. (A → B) → (¬B → ¬A) | FRG-1
5. ¬¬A → A | FRG-2
6. A → ¬¬A | FRG-3

And one inference rule, MP

Comment: I've tweaked the tags - "First-order logic" is (basically) the logic you get when you add quantifiers/variables, which isn't the case here. More saliently, what form of non-contradiction exactly are you looking for (i.e. what formula scheme in your particular language)? For me, your FRG3 is already a plausible "implication-and-negation-only" expression of non-contradiction.

Comment: What do you see as the Law of Non-Contradiction ... especially in terms of $\neg$ and $\to$, which are the only operators used in this system?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was thinking more like ¬(p → ¬p) would be LNC using just implication and negations.

Comment: @Bram28 ¬(p → ¬p) this

Comment: @vihan You really don;t want that: $p \to \neg p$ is equivalent to $\neg p$, and so  $\neg (p \to \neg p)$ is equivalent to $\neg \neg p$ .. and thus to $p$ ... which is not a tautology (and thus not derivable in this system) .. and it certainly is not what any reasonable interpretation of the law of contradiction would be.

Comment: Maybe it could be reasonable to pose non-contradiction as $p \rightarrow (\lnot p \rightarrow q)$?  In other words, if you have both $p$ and $\lnot p$ true, then you have a contradiction, so by explosion, you can conclude whatever proposition $q$ that you want.

Comment: Also, I think THEN-3 is redundant since it should be possible to derive it from THEN-1 and THEN-2 - right?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you would regard as an expresion of the Law of Non-COntradiction (would be good to add to your post!), but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction) states the Law of Contradiction as $\neg (P \land \neg P)$

As is, that statement cannot be derived from Frege's axioms, simply because Frege's system does not work with conjunctions... it only uses $\neg$'s and $\to$'s.

So, we could try and state the Law of Non-contradiction using $\neg$'s and $\to$'s by using certain elementary equivalences from Classical Logic.

For example, if we use the classical logic equivalence that $P \to Q \Leftrightarrow \neg (P \land \neg Q)$, then $\neg (P \land \neg P)$ could be written simply as $P \to P$ .. which is a theorem you can derive from Aixoms THEN-1 and THEN-2 fairly easily (most texts on axiom systems will have this proof ... [it appears on the second page of this document](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecse541/chapter8.pdf))

But we can also use $\neg (P \to Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land \neg Q$, in which case we get that $\neg (P \land \neg P)$ becomes $\neg \neg (P \to P)$.  Well, we already know that you can get $P \to P$ from THEN-1 and THEN-2, so using FRG-3 you'll then get $\neg \neg (P \to P)$.

FInally, we can say that $\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$, and that $P \to Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$. So with that: $\neg(P \land \neg P) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg \neg P \Leftrightarrow P \to \neg \neg P$ .. which simply *is* FRG-3.

This third suggestion is Noah's suggestion from Comments, and it would be my preferred choice as well: it says “if you have $P$, then you cannot (also) have $\neg P$ … which really seems to capture the spirit of the Law of Non-Contradiction, unlike $P \to P$, or $\neg \neg (P \to P)$.

And what about FRG-2, which is $\neg \neg P \to P$? Well, it is saying “if you don’t have $\neg P$, then at least you still have $P$”. In other words, this formula nicely captures the Law of Excluded Middle idea that *at least* one of $P$ and $\neg P$ is true, which we normally capture using $P \lor \neg P$. But that idea,  as the Wikipedia page points out, isn’t quite the idea of the Law of Non-Contradiction … the Law of Non-Contrsdiction says that *at most* one of them is true, i.e. that they are not both true. For that $P \to \neg \neg P$ seems to fit the bill just right.

Comment: Similarly, if in Frege's framework you *define* $P \land Q$ in general to be syntactic sugar for $\lnot(P \rightarrow \lnot Q)$, then $\lnot(P \land \lnot P)$ reduces to $\lnot\lnot(P \rightarrow \lnot\lnot P)$, which you can get pretty easily from two instances of FRG-3 and modus ponens.